# Why does y = 0 when I run println?

Tags: clojure

How come when I run

```
  (def y 0)
  (doseq [x (range 1000)] (if (or (= (mod x 3) 0) (= (mod x 5) 0)) (+ y x)))
  (println y)
```

it prints `0` as if no addition has taken place but

```
(doseq [x (range 1000)] (if (or (= (mod x 3) 0) (= (mod x 5) 0)) (println x)))
```

will print out all of the corresponding numbers that match the conditions?

Answer (score 3):

In clojure, values are immutable. `y` is, and will be 0 for all of eternity. `(+ y 1)` is 1, and will always be 1. `(+ y 1)` does not change the value of `y`, it simply evalutates to the result of adding 1 to the immutable value `y`.

Try this:

```
(println 
  (reduce 
    (fn [y x]
      (if (or (= (mod x 3) 0) 
              (= (mod x 5) 0)) 
        (+ y x) y))
  0 (range 1000)))
```

Here, we build up `y` over time by reducing over the range in question. If we match your condition, we add the next value (`x`). If we don't match your condition, we just return y.

Look up the `reduce` function.

*Note: there my be typos, I wrote this on my phone*

Answer (score 2):

Like in every other mainstream language, `+` in Clojure does not have side effects, and does not alter its input. There is no logic in your `doseq` which could alter the value of `y`.

In the second example, the `println` inside the `doseq` sees the temporary local values for `x`, which sometimes cause printing to occur.